# Applying same calcuation to each element of dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, large-data

I have a dataframe like this.

```
          user  tag1  tag2  tag3
0  Roshan ghai   0.0   1.0   1.0
1    mank nion   1.0   1.0   2.0
2   pop rajuel   2.0   0.0   1.0
3   random guy   2.0   1.0   1.0
```

I have to apply a calculation to each row. which is for each element x

```
x =(( specific tag's count for that user ##that element itself##))/ max no. of count of that tag ##max value of that column##)) * (ln(no. of total user ##lenth of df##)/(no. of of user having that tag ##no. of user having non 0 count for that particular tag or column ##))
```

I have used ## to describe that particular value. I have to do it for each element of dataframe what is the most efficient way to this as i have a large no. of elements . I am using python2.7.
output:

```
          user  tag1  tag2  tag3
0  Roshan ghai     0  .287     0
1    mank nion  .143  .287     0
2   pop rajuel  .287     0     0
3   random guy  .287  .287     0
```

I have just used the formula which i have written like for mank nion and tag1
x =((1.0)/2.0)*(ln(4/3) = .143 .

Comment: Can you add desired output and how you count first value in this output?

Comment: @jezrael i have added the output , count for that user is what i have in dataframe for that user&tag like for mank nion & tag1 it is 1.0. any other doubt?. please do help

Comment: @jezrael please do some help.

Comment: Please check solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select all values without first column by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html). Then use [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html), [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) of non 0 values and [`numpy.log`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.log.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print (df.ix[:, 'tag1':].max())
tag1    2.0
tag2    1.0
tag3    2.0
dtype: float64

print ((df.ix[:, 'tag1':] != 0).sum())
tag1    3
tag2    3
tag3    4
dtype: int64

df.ix[:, 'tag1':] = (df.ix[:, 'tag1':] / df.ix[:, 'tag1':].max() * 
                    (np.log(len(df) / (df.ix[:, 'tag1':] != 0).sum())))

print (df)
          user      tag1      tag2  tag3
0  Roshan-ghai  0.000000  0.287682   0.0
1    mank-nion  0.143841  0.287682   0.0
2   pop-rajuel  0.287682  0.000000   0.0
3   random-guy  0.287682  0.287682   0.0
```

Another solution with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
df.iloc[:, 1:] = (df1 / df1.max() * (np.log(len(df) / (df1 != 0).sum())))
print (df)
          user      tag1      tag2  tag3
0  Roshan-ghai  0.000000  0.287682   0.0
1    mank-nion  0.143841  0.287682   0.0
2   pop-rajuel  0.287682  0.000000   0.0
3   random-guy  0.287682  0.287682   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import io
temp = u"""          user  tag1  tag2  tag3
0  Roshan-ghai   0.0   1.0   1.0
1    mank-nion   1.0   1.0   2.0
2   pop-rajuel   2.0   0.0   1.0
3   random-guy   2.0   1.0   1.0"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), delim_whitespace=True)

maxtag1 = df.tag1.max()
maxtag2 = df.tag2.max()
maxtag3 = df.tag3.max()
number_users = len(df)
number_users_tag1 = len(df[df['tag1']!=0])
number_users_tag2 = len(df[df['tag2']!=0])
number_users_tag3 = len(df[df['tag3']!=0])
liste_values = [maxtag1,maxtag2,maxtag3,number_users,number_users_tag1,number_users_tag2,number_users_tag3]
```

Then you create a function which takes as input your row and these values and which outputs the desired three values. And use `apply`:

```
output = df.apply(lambda x: yourfunction(x, list_values))
```

Comment: using this method for 200 user wont be that good i guess. There are function which can do this in short and fast, I hope so.

Comment: I do this for dataframes with a few dozen thousands rows and it takes less than one minute. So it's quite effective, but far from optimal, indeed.